# Upgrading Cordova for non-cli apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I have a quite old version of cordova. For Android it's 3.6.4 and for iOS 2.9.1.

The latest version for Android is 5.1.1 and for iOS 4.1.1 and I would like to upgrade it.

However the application is a non-cli application and it's mainly standalone application.

I've noticed in https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/upgrade.html that it mentions

> Alternatively, you may attempt to use the platform update script. For
>   non-CLI projects, run:
>
> bin/update path/to/project

I'm using a mac OS for upgrading the cordova and I'm not so sure where I could find this script bin/update.

Any hints for how I could make the upgrade would be useful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have finally used the npm package manager as described in

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova

and install nodejs through brew for having cordova and npm.